# complicated notice question

Tags: united-states

My company released me after 28 years service on and effective May 24th with 6 months notice. if i find another job and advise them that they are released from the obligation to pay me have I resigned? I work in Texas. it may not seem important but if I resign i lose my shares. i believe that the activation of the termination clause in the contract is what matters, I am just relieving them of their obligation under that contract?

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  I would strongly suggest that you invest in a lawyer to review your actual contract and to advise you appropriately.  I wouldn't expect it to constitute a resignation but you really want that to come from a lawyer who practices in your state and has read your specific contract not some random dude on the internet.

Comment: "I am just relieving them of their obligation under that contract" - not necessarily - they may want you around for the 6 months to do things. It seems reasonable to assume cutting your notice short would be closer to a resignation than a termination, unless you can get them to agree to it (but a lawyer is indeed the person you should talk to).

Comment: This question is essentially asking for legal advice - if you get the wrong advice here (which you no doubt will) you could be shortchanging yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you are given 6 months notice *today* then you are still employed until exactly six months from now. In your case until 23rd of November. You still have to go to work, you get your normal pay, until 23rd of November.

You probably should find a new job with a starting date of November 24th. If you would like to start a new job earlier, you can discuss with your company whether they would agree to reduce the notice period.

If they don't agree to reduce the notice period, and you *really* want to start elsewhere earlier, then you can give notice yourself, which may have significant cost for you, for example if you lose share options if you resign. You'll have to figure out how much it would cost you and make your decision.

Comment: To add this answer, please don't be one of those people who get their end date and just coast. You're still getting paid to do your job. Do it to the best of your abilities as if you had to deal with the work you did after that date. People talk, and this will speak highly of your character in future endeavors!